# Upload large file in chunks with checkpoints

Tags: azure, storage

*I originally asked this question on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/67), but nobody responded yet, so I'm trying it here*.

We're using [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) to upload a large file and want to support pause/resume using *checkpoints*. However the upload doesn't finish and is stuck in the while loop:

```
TransferManager.Configurations.BlockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 MB

// create stream with 100 MB
var content = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 100 * 1024 * 1024)
    .Select(i => (byte)'b')
    .ToArray();
var source = new MemoryStream(content);

TransferCheckpoint checkPoint = null;
while (true)
{
    Console.Write(".");
    // Resume if there is already a checkpoint
    var context = checkPoint != null
        ? new SingleTransferContext(checkPoint)
        : new SingleTransferContext();

    context.ShouldOverwriteCallback = (src, dest) => true;
    context.LogLevel = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.LogLevel.Verbose;
    var recorder = new ProgressRecorder();
    context.ProgressHandler = recorder;
    try
    {
        // Interrupt upload after 20 seconds
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)))
        {
            await TransferManager.UploadAsync(source, blob, null, context, cts.Token);
        }
        // break if no exception occured, i.e. the upload finished
        break;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    checkPoint = context.LastCheckpoint; // save the last checkpoint
}
```

We added some debug output after saving the checkpoint, i.e. we used the Storage API to get all uncommitted blocks and matched it with `recorder`.

We get the following output:

```
Uncommitted blocks according to Storage API
A6689033-D96E-4F9B-B238-E27891C1B1FC/custom-upload-test3: 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 = 33554432 (32 MB)
Transfer statistics according to Data Movement Library
Transferred bytes: 33554432 (32 MB); Transfered: 0; Skipped: 0, Failed: 1

Uncommitted blocks according to Storage API
A6689033-D96E-4F9B-B238-E27891C1B1FC/custom-upload-test3: 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 = 46137344 (44 MB)
Transfer statistics according to Data Movement Library
Transferred bytes: 79691776 (76 MB); Transfered: 0; Skipped: 0, Failed: 2

Uncommitted blocks according to Storage API
A6689033-D96E-4F9B-B238-E27891C1B1FC/custom-upload-test3: 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 = 46137344 (44 MB)
Transfer statistics according to Data Movement Library
Transferred bytes: 121634816 (116 MB); Transfered: 0; Skipped: 0, Failed: 3

Uncommitted blocks according to Storage API
A6689033-D96E-4F9B-B238-E27891C1B1FC/custom-upload-test3: 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 + 4194304 = 46137344 (44 MB)
Transfer statistics according to Data Movement Library
Transferred bytes: 163577856 (156 MB); Transfered: 0; Skipped: 0, Failed: 4
```

We use the following snippet to get the list of uncommitted blocks:

```
var blockList = blob.DownloadBlockList(BlockListingFilter.Uncommitted);
var expr = string.Join(" + ", blockList.Select(b => b.Length));
var size = blockList.Sum(b => b.Length);
Console.WriteLine($"{blob.Name}: {expr} = {size} ({size/1024.0/1024.0} MB)");
```

So it almost looks like we're not capturing the context correctly because on every iteration the upload seems to restart.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Really, nobody uses this library?

Comment: Did you learn anything since? I'd love to upload in chunks

Comment: Nope, I don't think we ever solved this. We're hoping that we have a robust connection \*fingers crossed\* :-)